# Re-focusing a first responder in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I know how to create a `UIViewRepresentable` in SwiftUI in order to enable first responder functionality for a TextField:

```
struct FirstResponderTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    var placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FirstResponderTextField>) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FirstResponderTextField>) {
        uiView.placeholder = placeholder
        uiView.text = text

        if (!uiView.isFirstResponder) {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var firstResponderTextField: FirstResponderTextField

        init(_ firstResponderTextField: FirstResponderTextField) {
            self.firstResponderTextField = firstResponderTextField
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            firstResponderTextField.text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is attempting to "re-focus" this custom text field. So while this text field DOES get focused when my `ContentView` is initialized, I want to know how I can re-focus this text field programmatically, AFTER it has lost focus.

Here is my `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var textField1: String = ""
    @State var textField2: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                FirstResponderTextField(placeholder: "Text Field 1", text: $textField1)
                TextField("Text Field 2", text: $textField2)
            }
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                    // ???
                }, label: {
                    Text("Re-Focus Text Field 1")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I've tried. I thought maybe I could create a `@State` variable which can control the `FirstResponderTextField`, so I went ahead and changed my structs as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var textField1: String = ""
    @State var textField2: String = ""
    @State var isFocused: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                FirstResponderTextField(placeholder: "Text Field 1", text: $textField1, isFocused: $isFocused)
                TextField("Text Field 2", text: $textField2)
            }
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                    self.isFocused = true
                }, label: {
                    Text("Re-Focus Text Field 1")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstResponderTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    var placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var isFocused: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FirstResponderTextField>) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FirstResponderTextField>) {
        uiView.placeholder = placeholder
        uiView.text = text

        if (isFocused) {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
            isFocused = false
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var firstResponderTextField: FirstResponderTextField

        init(_ firstResponderTextField: FirstResponderTextField) {
            self.firstResponderTextField = firstResponderTextField
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            firstResponderTextField.text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

It does not appear to be working. I mean, it works when I first click the button, but stops working afterwards.

Also, I am now getting this warning:

> Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behaviour.

Is it possible to create a `UIViewRepresentable` that can be re-focused whenever I want?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be setting the isFocused to false in your FirstResponderTextField.

Instead, in FirstResponderTextField, observe the value changes in the isFocused binding, and set your control to being first responder or not accordingly.

I created a solution for you with an ObserableObject corresponding to the TextFieldState [in this gist on github](https://gist.github.com/ristkof/6ff2ebf4f38f91a777130658a0fd4215)

For future reference, this is what I changed:

- instead of `@State var isFocused: Bool = true` in ContentView, use `@ObservedObject var textFieldState = TextFieldState()`
- have a property `@ObservedObject var state: TextFieldState` in FirstResponderTextField
- simply do this in `FirstResponderTextField.updateUIView`:

```
    if state.isFirstResponder {
        uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```